# Mono for Android cannot find assets file

Tags: xamarin.android, assets

I'm frustrated after many tries to make it work, I want to read a text file out of assets folder while using MonoDevelop and mono for android.

I followed the tutorial here:
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_android_assets

but I get this:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: Exception of type'Java.IO.FileNotFoundException' was thrown.
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <0x00080>
at Android.Content.Res.AssetManager.Open (string) <0x0012b>
at Application.Android.AppActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0009b>
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005f>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.ee3982cf-bdcd-4242-9d0f-0d1b3908a490 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>

      --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.io.FileNotFoundException: read_assets.txt
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
at application.android.AppActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
at application.android.AppActivity.onCreate(AppActivity.java:36)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I opened up the apk file, there was no assets folder inside, did I do anything wrong?

And by the way, I'm using emulators

UPDATE:
I'm sorry, it's a typo, i missed a 's' in my file name, so everything is ok now, how do I delete this post?

Comment: Don't delete - I think you should add the answer yourself - it'll be useful for others who find the same problem

Comment: Please answer the question yourself and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a typo mistake I've made, the file in Assets folder was named "read_asset.txt", but I wrote "read_assets.txt" in my code, sorry. But I still haven't figured it out why apk structure is different from java based packages.